# Choose serializer for nested association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I am using Active Model Serializer in my Rails API but cannot get the nested serializers to work (I believe due to the fact that I have multiuple serializers for the same resource).  My models are setup such that:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_paranoid
    has_many :check_ins
end

class CheckIn < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :weigh_in, dependent: :destroy
end

class WeighIn < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :check_in
end
```

In my `ProgramsController` I have the following:

```
def index
    programs = Client.find(params[:client_id]).programs
    render json: programs, status: :ok, each_serializer: API::ProgramSerializer, include: "**"
end
```

And in my `API::ProgramSerializer` I have the following:

```
class API::ProgramSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :created_at, :position, :id

    has_many :check_ins, each_serializer: API::CheckInsIndexSerializer
end
```

The issue I'm running into is that I have **both** an `API::CheckInsIndexSerializer` as well as an `API::CheckInSerializer`.  It seems like the `include: "**"` forces Rails to use the `API::CheckInSerializer` despite me specifying that I'd like to use the `API::CheckInsIndexSerializer`.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by modifying both the `ProgramsController` and the `API::ProgramSerializer` the following:

```
def index
    programs = Client.find(params[:client_id]).programs
    render json: programs, status: :ok, each_serializer: API::ProgramSerializer
end

class API::ProgramSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :created_at, :position, :id, :check_ins

    def check_ins
        ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(object.check_ins,  each_serializer: API::CheckInsIndexSerializer)
    end
end
```

I had to remove the `include: "**"` and define how to load the `check_ins` explicitly.

Comment: https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition